# Importing Outlook emails into Gmail - Getting Unknown Sender

Tags: backup, microsoft-outlook, gmail, sync, exchange

I want to backup my Outlook email into Gmail.

I have setup my Gmail account in Outlook using IMAP like is suggested here - http://www.keenerliving.com/importing-outlook-into-gmail - and I can successfully upload Outlook emails into Gmail, but Exchange mail doesn't copy across the sender and receivers. All Exchange emails in Gmail are listed as sent by (unknown sender).

How do you upload Exchange emails into Gmail from Outlook while maintaining the correct From and To email addresses?

Answer (score 1):

Don't use Outlook to copy e-mails.

Use Windows Live Mail (which is part of the Windows Live Essentials suite) and set up connections to both Exchange and Google Mail using IMAP.

Then it is simply a case of copying the folders or individual e-mails with the e-mail address intact.

[Source](http://bradkellett.com/p/microsoft-exchange-to-gmail-migration-with-imap/)

Comment: Agreed. Outlook mangles headers.

Answer (score 0):

Essentially, you'll have to follow a two-step process:

1. Copy emails from PST to Exchange mailbox (will mirror in IMAP4 mailbox)
2. Copy emails from IMAP4 mailbox to Gmail mailbox

Besides using Microsoft Outlook 2007 to move emails from PST to an Exchange mailbox (will mirror in IMAP4 mailbox), I also found it helpful to use Thunderbird to move emails from the IMAP4 mailbox to Gmail.  I used Virtual PC 2007 and the pre-configured VHD of Exchange Server 2007 SP1 that Microsoft provides for evaluation purposes.

MS Virtual PC 2007 SP1
http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=24439

MS Exchange Server 2007 SP1 VHD
http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=14901

Below is the short-hand detail (I would post the links to technet and other references that helped me a lot,  but I can only post two links):

Host PC Desktop -> Start -> Control Panel -> Network Connections -> Properties -> Install -> Virtual Machine Network Services
Virtual PC -> Edit -> Settings -> Networking Settings -> Adapter 1 -> Select the desktop network connection that you just updated
Virtual PC -> Edit -> Settings -> Shared Folders -> to copy any data or installation files on your host desktop
Virtual PC Desktop -> Start -> Control Panel -> Network Connections -> Properties -> TCP/IP -> Obtain IP + Obtain DNS

Exchange Management Console -> Organization Configuration -> Hub Transport -> New Accepted Domain
Exchange Management Console -> Organization Configuration -> Hub Transport -> E-mail Address Policies -> Edit -> Add -> Select accepted domain + Set as Reply 
Exchange Management Console -> Organization Configuration -> Hub Transport -> Accepted Domains -> + Set as default

Exchange Management Console -> Server Configuration > Client Access > POP3 and IMAP4 -> Authentication -> Plain text logon

Administrative Tools -> Domain Controller Security Policy -> Account Policies -> Password Policy -> Set preferred requirements (Ex. Disable complexity)
Administrative Tools -> Domain Security Policy -> Account Policies -> Password Policy -> Set preferred requirements (Ex. Disable complexity)
Administrative Tools -> Services -> Microsoft Exchange IMAP4 -> Start + Automatic

Exchange Management Console -> Recipient Configuration -> Mailbox -> New Mailbox -> User Mailbox -> Create mailbox for new user + Select mailbox database

Exchange Management Console -> Organization Configuration -> Add Exchange Administrator -> Select user + Exchange Organization Administrator role

Install Outlook on virtual hard drive (not recommended in general but works for transfer to Gmail)
Copy PST file to virtual hard drive

Add Exchange account (Uncheck cached Exchange mode)
Add PST file

Add IMAP4 account to connect to your Exchange mailbox through IMAP (see account details below)
Add Gmail account

user@LITWAREINC.COM
LITWAREINC/user
IMAP: EX07SP1.LITWAREINC.COM:993 (SSL)
SMTP: EX07SP1.LITWAREINC.COM:587 (STARTTLS)
Test Account Settings -> Should log onto incoming mail server but may not successfully send test e-mail message (not necessary for transfer)

Copy from PST to Exchange mailbox (will mirror in IMAP4 mailbox)
Copy from IMAP4 mailbox to Gmail mailbox (I tested this successfully with Outlook but used Thunderbird for the mass transfer)

Note: My trial version expired (incorrectly) and would sometimes restart.  Occassionally, I had to restart Microsoft Exchange services.
Administrative Tools -> Services -> Microsoft Exchange Active Directory Topology Service -> Restart
Administrative Tools -> Services -> Microsoft Exchange Information Store -> Restart